# Are there way of proving that polynomials are relatively prime using number theory or abstract algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, analysis, number-theory, contest-math

This question is inspired by [question A5 from the Putnam Mathematical Competition](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2014.pdf):

> Let
>   $$P_n(x) = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + \cdots + nx^{n-1}.$$
>   Prove that polynomials $P_j(x)$ and $P_k(x)$ are relatively prime for all positive integers $j$ and $k$ with $j \neq k$.

I saw [their solutions](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2014s.pdf), and it is interesting but I think a different way is to perhaps use abstract algebra. I saw another question on Math.se: [Relatively Prime over C](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435486/showing-polynomials-are-relatively-prime-over-mathbb-c)

Is there another way to solve the problem, aside from the solutions they suggestion? In particular, something from number theory or abstract algebra.

Comment: An additional solution using $p$-adic valuations is mentioned, this matches your criteria. It is not quite clear what you want. Further, I find it  strange that you do (edit: did) not even include the problem itself here (edit: leaving this work for somebody else to do).

Comment: @quid, sorry. I linked it because I was sure I was going to mess something up in typing the problem. Im sorry, i wont do this anymore.

Comment: There's a theorem that say that a polynomial is irreducible if it takes on "too many" prime values. There's probably a theorem that says two polynomials are relatively prime if they take on too many relatively prime values. But it will be an "if", not an "if and only if" result.